# how to get real composite name in SWT.Show event

Tags: events, swt, show, rcp

I want to log the information of user's action, such as button click, show composite. So I use event listener. When I use SWT.FocusIn, I can get the real composite name, but when I use SWT.Show I can't get the real class name.

```
Listener listener = new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        switch (event.type) {
            case SWT.FocusIn: {
                if(event!=null&&event.widget!=null){
                    Control parent = ((Control)event.widget).getParent();
                    while(parent!=null&&(parent.toString().startsWith("Composite")
                                                ||parent.toString().startsWith("Group")
                                                ||parent.toString().startsWith("Splitter")
                                                )){
                        parent = parent.getParent();
                    }
                    if(parent!=null){
                        **//This place I can get "SWT.FocusIn:DoSomethingComposite"(The subclass of Composite).**
                        log.info("SWT.FocusIn:" + parent.toString());
                    }   
                }
                break;
            }
            case SWT.Show: {
                if (event.widget != null) {
                    if(event.widget instanceof Composite) {
                        Composite composite = (Composite)(event.widget);
                        **//But this place I just get "SWT.Show:Composite".**
                        log.info("SWT.Show:" + event.widget.toString());
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}   
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.Show, listener);
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.FocusIn, listener);
```

Comment: `SWT.Show` is usually only sent when menus are shown. What are you expecting it to be generated for?

Comment: I just want to log all the user's action, such as composite show event.When I use the SWT.FocusIn I can get the real composite name. But when the UI has default focus control, it will log the action which is generated by system. But I just want to log the user's action. If I use SWT.Show I can't get the real name. Is there a event will give what I need?